# Android app got suspended on Google Play Store on first publish

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I'm trying to publish my Android app on the Google Play store, but it got suspended due to a policy violation, specifically:

> **Issue: Violation of Webviews and Affiliate Spam policy**
>   We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to a website or provide a webview of a website without permission from the website owner or administrator.

A bit of information about my app:

- this is the first time I'm publishing the app, it was never published before
- i stated in the description that it is the official app for my website, also providing a link to it
- it's a hybrid app, built using Cordova and Angular, which I created from scratch forking my website's codebase and making some changes
- it is indeed a WebView, but the website's codebase has been completely repackaged into the app, and there's no direct link to the website

So my questions are: where do you think the *actual root cause* of the issue is, and what would be the best course of action for me to have my app published? As far as I can see I have these options available:

1. **Republish the app** with a different package and app names, but if that gets suspended again, I'm worried about losing my developer account permanently
2. **File an appeal**, and provide proof of ownership of the website (if that's even the root cause), although they don't specify what kind of proof they might be looking for. I have a print of Google Search console domain verification, and several screenshot from my hosting dashboard on Firebase, but I wonder if that's acceptable proof of ownership

Thanks for any advice, I'm fairly new to publishing apps and I'm worried about doing it the wrong way, or worse, getting my account permanently deleted.

Comment: Did you solve it finally? I'm facing the same issue. How did you solve the issue?

Comment: @SubhasishNath I did solve the issue eventually, by filing an appeal to the developers support. As stated by my accepted answer, I tried to provide as much information as I could to prove I was the actual owner of the website I claimed (hosting and email confirmation, etc.). After a day or so I got my app reinstated. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and [the Help Center page regarding appropriate topics for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MikeM. There's a site in Stackoverflow to ask this kind of questions?

Comment: @E_Blue Not that I know of, sorry. I know it's kinda lame, but Reddit is probably more suitable for questions like this, 'cause it usually ends up a discussion of opinions rather than factual answers, since nobody involved is going to be speaking for Google officially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone can do the same for your site and publish an app. I got my app suspended some time ago too since I hadn't gone through the policy of `webview`. You have the solution with you

> File an appeal, and provide proof of ownership of the website (if that's even the root cause), although they don't specify what kind of proof they might be looking for. I have a print of Google Search console domain verification, and several screenshots from my hosting dashboard on Firebase, but I wonder if that's acceptable proof of ownership

This way, Google will be able to realize that you are not an affiliate trying to make more income by redirecting users to a certain link for accessing the website

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to go for the appeal so. Given your past experience with the issue, do you have any indication if that's enough, or acceptable proof, to provide them with screenshots of my hosting dashboard for example?

Comment: do submit as much as you have and show your email u used from domain registration as identical to the one on play store, They can request more. Also, ensure your app is smooth and has no bugs or keeps freezing. that's a policy too. :)

Comment: How can I file an appeal? Thanks

Comment: @valhallarossferrer You can go through the appeal submission form:  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2993242